# Convert Date format in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert the date format of a column to (MM/DD/YYYY) but it doesn't work

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DimDate 
ADD FormattedFullDateAlternateKey date;

UPDATE dbo.DimDate
SET FormattedFullDateAlternateKey = CONVERT(varchar, FullDateAlternateKey, 101);
```

It actually works when I just do a select:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, FullDateAlternateKey, 101) AS FullDateAlternateKey
FROM dbo.DimDate;
```

I want to store the new column with the new date format in my database, but I couldn't, any help please

Comment: Dates, when stored correctly as a `date` dataype, don't have a format. You only format it for display, which you do in your application. SSMS just has a default format it uses. So you are storing it completely correctly. You just need to format it for display.

Comment: Dates should be stored as dates.   You will have far more functionality than a mm/dd/yyyy string

Comment: Just an aside  varchar without a length is risky.

Comment: I changed the date format, but the result remained the same ,  it still displays a duplicated column of FullDateAlternateKey

Comment: What do you mean you changed the date format? In your presentation layer? Then you need to show your application code. The problem is unrelated to SQL Server, the date is a `date`; you need to ask about how to change that presented value in your application code (whatever that is).

Comment: The column `FullDateAlternateKey` has the format (e.g., 2005-01-07), and I want to convert it to (e.g., 07-01-2005). This is my problem because I want to map this column with another one which has the second format.

Comment: @Ilhamx as we keep saying to you, that column doesn't have a format! Its a date, dates don't have formats. What are you actually trying to do? You can compare it to another date without caring about the format.

Comment: as my understanding "map" means you need to compare with another source where date in different format? (IMHO) so you can keep datetime column type but when you linking data you can convert your column values to different formats...  check function Convert in SQL example: ...WHERE CONVERT(varchar,YOURCOLUMN,107) == [OTHERCOLUMN-as-STRING_Specific_DateFormat]...

Comment: @PowerMouse yes I want to connect this table with another one on Visual Studio  , Ok I'll try this one thanks a lot :)

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in the table you want to *link* (do you mean *join*) to? Because if it is also stored as a `date` you don't need to convert anything. if its a varchar, you could be better off converting that to a `date` than converting a date to a string.

Comment: no it's also date

Comment: There you don't need any conversions, SQL will correctly compare a date to a date.

Comment: IlhamX- @DaleK giving you main tip - follow up. DONT convert datetime unless you need to return it in specific format. compare datetime to datetime (its SAME datatypes), any conversion from datetime to format it would be a varchar. DO NOT DO IT unless you need to return that specifically formatted data in select statement to client, application or report.  if you need to link tables by datetime, please provide tables with columns and relation between them (one to one, one to many, many to many etc...)